# Attribute values with white space are not allowed in Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition (ODSEE) 11g LDAP server

Tags: java, oracle11g, ldap

I have an field in application which accepts `"abc  123"`(2 spaces in btw abc and 123) and `"abc      123"`(4 spaces in btw abc and 123) as answers but when submitted and called ODSEE 11g LDAP server, LDAP server is throwing an error:

> javax.naming.directory.AttributeInUseException: [LDAP: error code 20 - Attribute Or Value Exists]; Remaining name: 'cn=XXXXX,ou=YYYYY,o=ZZZZZ'
>           at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3063)

Can any one of you please let me know if ODSEE assumes that `"abc  123"` (2 spaces) and `"abc      123"` (4 spaces) are same answers? If yes, then how can I make changes in Java application to save these two values in ODSEE LDAP with out any error?

Comment: You need to post a bit more information about what your problem is and especially about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My question is ODSEE is not allowing an multi value attribute value to have both "abc  123" (2 spaces between abc & 123) and "abc      123" (4 spaces between abc & 123).It is thinking these two values are same but ideally they are not same.It is assuming "abc  123" (2 spaces between abc & 123)= "abc      123" (4 spaces between abc & 123)I have to write this clearly because stackoverflow is truncating spaces between abc & 123.

Comment: check operation is set to Replace instead of Add. http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Modify%20Request